# How to give command line input to an android app

Tags: android-layout

I have built one wifi registration app..that register wifi password automatically. I want to make an app that accept wifi password through command line.

Now I am storing my WiFi password in the app only. I want to give wifi password through command line. Please suggest is this possible. If yes then how???

Wifi password changes every 10 days. And I need to open my app and then manually i need to change wifi password. I want to avoid this. So please help me.

Help me with an exampl....
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say command line - you mean through adb?

Comment: yes....on installing app...plz help...

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions
1. Do something similar to what this SO answer says. [Adb shell commands to change settings or perform tasks on a phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203495/adb-shell-commands-to-change-settings-or-perform-tasks-on-a-phone/) and [How to turn off Wifi via ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033757/turn-off-wifi-via-adb)

Basically open up wifi settings through adb commands and then enter the password through adb shell commands

2. Use MonkeyRunner or similar tools to achieve the same
3. Use Android Testing framework to write a script to accomplish the same.

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

I would personally use 3 because its much more robust as opposed to 1 & 2.