# Android Test Platform Generator using java

Tags: java, android

So I have received a task to develop a prototype software for testing the software/hardware component of android. Example: By using the software I can send a command from my PC to my android to change the color of screen display without interacting with the devices(touch,shake or other possible gestures). I would like to know how do I actually start. The whole idea is actually messed up in my mind. Because after a few days of research I haven't found any topic related to what I am going to do. I am still fresh with java so please go easy on me :) Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing personal, but I am always surprising seeing people assigned to complex tasks to persons who got zero experience in given field.

Answer (score 0):

hi this is very much feasible. First you need is a web service that connects your software to your phone. When you give command on your software, the command should go trigger the web service which in turn should send a push notification to the phone to execute your command. You will be needed to create a some sort of listener and push notification system on your phone(Hint GCM may work). Also you will need to add permissions to your app that is listening to the notifications. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: how about using hardware connection like usb? (adb bridge)

Comment: Please elaborate what you trying to ask. it is a huge topic

Comment: Oh what i trying to say is rather than using web service, is it possible to use hardware connection(usb) to push notification to the phone to execute command?

Comment: Basically you need to issue adb commands. Check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203495/adb-shell-commands-to-change-settings-or-perform-tasks-on-a-phone

Comment: okay thank you for all the feedback your help is appreciated. God bless you :)

Comment: Comment here if you need any further help