# Android adb shell command to play sound from the command line

Tags: android, adb

I have a set of rooted android devices I can access through adb over tcp/ip.
I am trying to identify a specific one by playing a sound from the command line (one of the .ogg files from /system/media/audio).

I know I could probably build an app for this but it feels like an overkill to use an APK, and I'm hoping there is a more native way. I already know how to start intents from the command line.

Things I have tried :

- Investigated using `service call media.player` but could not find any useful reference about the syntax. I can see with `dumpsys media.player` references about AwesomePlayer but couln't get anything going.
- Tried to find a compiled version of "[/system/bin/media](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/media/)" from the android source code, as it is missing from the device, but without any luck so far.
- Tried to build a command line java app to call android.media.MediaPlayer with `dalvikvm` but my knowledge of Android and java is too limited (class compiled but complained about missing dependencies at runtime)

Any ideas?

Comment: Hope this can be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203495/adb-shell-commands-to-change-settings-or-perform-tasks-on-a-phone

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually I'm trying to avoid launching a user app and looking for a more system native solution if possible.

Comment: I found this article: http://a3nm.net/blog/android_cli.html 
There 'stagefright' is mentioned. 
In the AOSP 'stagefried' is mentioned too: https://source.android.com/devices/media.html 
May be you can try to look in this direction.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, just posted the solution I'm currently using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some trial and error, I will answer what is now working for me.

Based on [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618182/how-to-play-ringtone-alarm-sound-in-android), I found the following java code to be the bare minimum to play some sound through the speaker. The MediaPlayer class seems the only one that will play with no user interaction, as others need a real activity context...

```java
public class Beep {

    public static void main(String[] a) {

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource("/system/media/audio/alarms/Ticktac.ogg");
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("Beep", "IOException", e);
        }
}
```

([actual working example is here](https://gist.github.com/bendenoz/d9832f24caa6c826f1c4))

This must then be [compiled as a dex file](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/shell-dalvikvm-Command-to-Run-Java-Application.html), linked to android.jar,
and can finally be run from the adb shell command line using `app_process` (not dalvikvm) :

```sh
export CLASSPATH=./Beep.dex
app_process /system/bin Beep /system/media/audio/ringtones/Beep-beep.ogg
```

It is not the one-liner I was hoping for but does what I needed...

Answer (score 6):

[As seen in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437599/how-to-play-one-audio-file-in-android-using-adb-command,)

you can do this with a single shell command if you have a file there:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d /sdcard/somthing/example.wav -t audio/wav
```

Comment: You can also use `audio/*` for any type of audio file.

Comment: If I try to run this in Termux, I get `Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent ...` Or does this work only on rooted devices?

Comment: All right, it seems to work if I prepend the path with `file://`.

Answer (score 1):

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///sdcard/download/mysong.mp3 -t audio/mp3

You can use this as an cmd command

"sdcard/download" is the path for "download" folder in the Internal storage.

You can also use the path  "storage/emulated/0/download/"  for the internal storage's download folder"

You will get the below error if,
file not found due to incorrect location or filename has spaces
or re-running the command again before closing the previous activity

file name must not have any spaces otherwise give it as
a string